# function inside function - maximum value

Tags: functions

I am trying to calculate my algorithm efficiency as I posted in [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16076/traveling-salesman-heldkarp-algorithm-big-improvement). One of the things that I need to do is to find the maximum value between 1 to $G$ that belongs to $$f(x) = 2f(x - 1) - 1; F(0) = 4$$

My question is how do I do that, I got no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple recurrences like this, it's easiest to solve by substituting and figuring out the pattern.
$$\begin{align*}f(x) &= 2f(x-1) -1 \\
       &= 2\big(2f(x-2)-1\big)-1\\
       &= 2\Big(2\big(2f(x-3)-1\big)-1\Big)-1\\
       &\ \vdots \\
       &= 2^kf(x-k) - \sum_{i=1}^k 2^{k-1} \\
       &= 2^kf(x-k) - (2^k - 1)\,.
\end{align*}
$$

Now, set $k=x$ and we get
$$f(x) = 2^xf(0) - 2^x + 1 = 3\cdot 2^x + 1\,.$$

There are various methods for solving more complex recurrences; searching this site and Wikipedia will give you plenty of help.